# Installing Jekyll Gem: bin/ruby: invalid option -H (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently trying to install the jekyll gem, but it is failing with the error below. Can anybody help me in finding the cause? Please note that i am a ruby/gem noob. Until now i have just used gem install and was always happy with it. Thanks a lot!

```
sudo gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/mboehm.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:54: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/mboehm in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /mboehm.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/mboehm.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /mboehm.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/**fast-stemmer-1.0.2** for inspection.
Results logged to /mboehm.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I fixed this with renaming my volume from "Macintosh HD" to a name without space (for me: "HDD")

It was never a problem until ruby 2.0.0

Comment: This is actually the case on my Volume! Will definitely try that. Thanks alot!

Comment: I finally managed to try it and it worked like a charm. Took me quite some time, as i was a little anxious about breaking things with this renaming :-)